# How to trigger a click function on li that contains iframe?

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

I have multiple li that contains iframe. But when i click on the li it doesn't fire the click function instead it plays the video that the iframe holds.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.li-class').click(function(){
        alert('clicked');
    });
});
```

I have also tried this -

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("iframe").each(function () {

            var iframe = $(this);
            iframe.on("load", function () {
                iframe.contents().click(function (event) {
                    iframe.trigger("click");
                });
            });

            iframe.click(function () {
                alert('clicked');
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: If you don't want user to be able to interact with the iframe contents, overlay the iframe with a transparent div.

Answer (score 0):

So i found out the solution.

I have added a div inside li, made that absolute, added click function. Worked fine! :)

HTML:

```
<li class="li-class">
                <iframe width="585" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videolink" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>

                <div class="video-overlay"></div>
</li>
```

CSS:

```
.li-class {
        position: relative;
    }

    .video-overlay {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

jQuery:

```
$('.video-overlay').click(function(){
        alert('clicked');
    });
```